# drag drop element on image map get value

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I have a image map and want to drag and drop one element i.e. pin on Country Map. When the pin drops on map. I need that image map ID.

```
<p id="draggable" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 40px; cursor: move; z-index:100;"><img src="images/pin1.png"/></p>
<img src="image.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Elements" usemap="#elementmap" />
    <map name="elementmap">
    <area id="element1"  class="droppable" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Element 1"/>
    <area id="element2" class="droppable" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Element 2"/>
</map>
```

jQuery code is like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: '#draggable',
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");

        var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");

        alert(targetElem);
        alert(draggableId);
        alert(droppableId);

    }
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fguru/ZKQ2x/2/

Is there any way around.

Comment: What are the results of your alerts?

Comment: nothing, looks like it's not even going in droppable function. I tried hover function and it works fine. ( just to check the ids).
$('.droppable').hover(
  function () {
    
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
  },
  function () {
    
  }
);

Comment: Strange, you're code is working on my system. You're sure that the right jQuery-libaries are included? No errors on Firebug/F12?

Comment: Can I see jsfiddle plz.

Comment: I replaced your `map`/`area` with a `div`, http://jsfiddle.net/abfnL/. Maybe you could try some different nested `div's` first?

Comment: Hi Pieter, here is the jsFiddle I have updated. http://jsfiddle.net/fguru/ZKQ2x/2/ 
If you do with div it works but with image map it doesn't work.

Comment: Very strange, the HTML5 `ondrop` function isn't working either.

Comment: any other solution or trick in your mind.

Comment: Probably you can find the X and Y of the 'drop location' and match that with your area's?

Comment: Its not being dropped on the map. Please heck this fiddle. I have added "revert: invalid" to show the functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/varunshk2/ZKQ2x/24/
I am also trying to find a solution. Once you find the solution, please update here. It will be very helpfull

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Try adding `draggable="true"` property to your img tag

Comment: This is not the solution. Found the issue exist even after adding this code. http://jsfiddle.net/varunshk2/ZKQ2x/24/